# Why pgfplots's histogram vertical axis magnitude in %?

Tags: pgfplots, statistics, histogram

According to example from manual for [pgfplots](https://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) (page 512), the default behaviour of `hist={density}` is a plot

[image]

My MWE result y-axis magnitude realize in `%` (not in per-one). Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{Histogram}
1.26
1.22
1.21
1.25
1.22
1.21
1.26
1.24
1.23
1.21
1.19
1.21
1.15
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0]
\addplot [hist={density}] table [y index=0] {Histogram};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here the density means `sum_{i in bins} bin_width * bin height = 1`, not `sum_{i in bins} bin height = 1`. What you expect is frequency, not density.